# Can I use a ZFS ZEVO-managed USB hard disk for Time Machine backups and does it offer de-deduplication?

Tags: time-machine, macos, zfs

## ZEVO support for Time Machine

Can I use a [ZEVO](http://tenscomplement.com/our-products/zevo-silver-edition)-managed USB hard disk for Time Machine backups?

### ZFS dedup

Will ZEVO and Time Machine give me de-duplication (which is sorely missing from Time Machine on HFS+, especially if you backup multiple machines to the same disk)?

Comment: FWIW, the "Silver Edition" (the only one available today) does not support de-duplication (needs Platinum) or encryption.

Comment: For the comment about encryption … [How can ZFS be used with encryption on OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52919/8546)

Comment: [Time Machine, ZFS and deduplication](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35958/8546)

Answer (score 3):

In the Time Machine pane of System Preferences, add any ZFS dataset.

For the first backup to that dataset, the operating system will:

1. create a sparse bundle disk image (…`.sparsebundle`) at the root of that dataset
2. attach the image, after which you'll see a volume named *Time Machine Backups*.

For each subsequent backup to that dataset, the OS will:

1. attach the image, after which you'll see the *Time Machine Backups* volume.

Time Machine routines with ZFS are similar or identical to the routines that apply when backing up to a device – such as an Apple Time Capsule – that uses AFP.

---

How can one recover from TM after new/reinstallation? New OS installation knows nothing about ZFS to TM image is unreachable.

Comment: Good point. Probably only works in combination with a file server (as a restore over the network), or by copying the sparse bundles over to a disk in a supported format.

Comment: Please: the question about *restoration* should be separate. There will be a multiple answers, which could become confusing under the [opening questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/39671/8546) about *backup*.

Comment: I refuse to think about restoration separate from backup. What is the point of a backup if not to later restore it?

Comment: No offence intended. I may revisit this question after the banner of changes, which appeared around the time of WWDC, is lifted from the ZEVO web site.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine backups can only be stored on HFS+ volumes. The reason is that Time Machine relies on the ability to create new hard links to existing directories, which you cannot do in ZFS.

Comment: How about HFS+ in a sparse bundle on ZFS? This is how Time Machine works over the network, right? Would that work (and give me the benefits of de-duplication and encryption)?

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, in principle, that should work. As far as de-duplication and encryption go, I don't remember from what ZFS versions those are available. But if Zevo offers them, you should be OK.

Comment: Wish for the restore interface of Time Machine to work with ZFS snapshots … a fuller answer will fit better under a question about restoration.